# what is font-display CSS feature?

Tags: css, sass, web-frontend

For my website, I am getting following feedback from Google's PageSpeed Insights: Leverage the font-display CSS feature to ensure text is user-visible while web fonts are loading. What does that mean?

Comment: Here is an article you might find answers your question
https://css-tricks.com/font-display-masses

Answer (score 29):

CSS `font-display` allows you to control how web fonts are swapped with system fonts while/after they load. Lighthouse is telling you that you're loading a large amount of font data using `@font-face` so there will be lag (up to several seconds) where your content is blank while waiting for the fonts to load.

You can change this so that a fallback font (from your local system) loads right away and then gets swapped with your web fonts once they're loaded. **(be aware that your fonts may have different sizes and cause things to jump around when they load)**.

Consider a structure like this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans Regular";
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
}

p {
  font-family: "Open Sans Regular", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
```

`font-display:swap;` means when the page renders, all paragraph tags will use the FIRST AVAILABLE fallback font until `Open Sans Regular` has loaded. (In this case Helvetica on a Mac and Arial on Windows).

**This gives you initial content on the screen in several milliseconds instead of potentially waiting several seconds for a font to load.**

Comment: What happens if you don't use `font-display: swap`? It seems to like it will behave the same way.

Comment: The question is about how to improve Google Lighthouse score. It's best practice to have content on the screen as soon as possible and font-display: swap accomplishes that.

Answer (score 2):

Also Preload web fonts 
Use  to fetch your font files earlier.

[Ensure text remains visible during webfont load](https://web.dev/font-display/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=unknown)

Answer (score -9):

**Font Feature** is  a technique  to use  advanced text styles and effects as designed by the font developer. A font may support a number of features: some examples include different kinds of ligatures, tabular numbers, or small caps.This picture explain much better  [image]

You can solve this issue by using @fontface or you can also try different setting of `font-display`.

Comment: This answer doesn't address what `font-display` does as it relates to page speed and loading of `@font-face`. A copy & paste from a Google search doesn't really help improve the community's knowledge...